# Why one case causes "backward through the graph a second time" error but the other doesn't?

Tags: pytorch, autograd

**Preconditions**

```py
import torch.nn as nn
class Net(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self,input,H,output):
        super(Net,self).__init__()
        self.linear1=nn.Linear(input,H)
        self.linear2=nn.Linear(H,output)
 
        
    def forward(self,x):
        x=torch.sigmoid(self.linear1(x))  
        x=self.linear2(x)
        return x
```

**case1**: no erorr

```py
net = Net(2, 3, 2)
input = torch.randn(2)
loss1 = net(input).sum()
loss2 = net(input).sum()/2

loss1.backward()
loss2.backward()
```

**case 2**: `RuntimeError: Trying to backward through the graph a second time (or directly access saved tensors after they have already been freed)`

```py
torch.autograd.set_detect_anomaly(True)

net = Net(2, 3, 2)
input = torch.randn(2)
loss1 = net(input).sum()
loss2 = loss1/2

loss1.backward()
loss2.backward()
```

**My question:** *I have read some answers like [this](https://discuss.pytorch.org/t/runtimeerror-trying-to-backward-through-the-graph-a-second-time-but-the-buffers-have-already-been-freed-specify-retain-graph-true-when-calling-backward-the-first-time/6795) to this type questions*: it causes the error that the graph is discarded after the first backward. If so, then in the first case the two loss share a children graph with `net` as its root, therefore the first backward should have discarded the graph leading to error in the second backward, which does not. Why?

Answer (score 0):

Comparing the graph(s) in each setting should help us understand this subtlety.

The network `net` only has input leaves so calling `net(input)` twice will create two separate graphs:

```
input  --> y1 = net(input) --> loss1 = y1.sum()    <-- backward
      \
       --> y2 = net(input) --> loss2 = y2.sum()/2  <-- backward
```

While in the second case, you have:

```
input  --> y1 = net(input)  --> loss1 = y1.sum()   <-- backward
                           \                        
                            --> loss2 = l1/2       <-- backward
```

In the first case, you have two graphs and are passing through each one once. In the second case, you have a single graph with two heads since `loss2` is computed directly from `loss1`, therefore when the 2nd `backward` call occurs, the graph has already been (partially) cleared because of the 1st `backward` call.

If you want to look closer at the graph of `net`:

```
layer1.weight layer1.bias layer2.weight layer2.bias  sigmoid
       \             \           \             \         \ 
 x --> x1        --> x2      --> x2        --> x3    --> y1
```

So when infering y1=net(input), both `input` (`=x`) and {`layer1.weight`, `layer1.bias`, `layer2.weight`, `layer2.bias`} are leaves.

Comment: So `net.parameters()` altogether are the leaves? Considering this is a MLP, why isn't it  the case that the first layer parameters are the leaves and the latter ones are not to be dumped after first backward.

Comment: "The network net has no input leaves so calling net(input) twice will create two separate graphs" seems to suggests that if the input has gradient, then there will be only one graph created. But it is not true. I have tried modifying input as `input = torch.randn(2, requires_grad=True)` in the first case and no error occur either. How do you explain this?

Comment: "why isn't it the case that the first layer parameters are the leaves" that's because the layers following the 1st layer are also leaves (see edit). Also, I was not clear with my statement: net's parameters are all leaves, In the 1st scenario you are computing two separate graphs from the same input, the computation is distinct and the graphs are not attached.